# System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Tags: trigger, error

I have two questions.
Firstly, is the following code correct to update the field report__C which simply displays the email address of the person who created the case.

Secondly, when i tried to test this trigger b creating a new case i get the following error 
"System.FinalException: Record is read-only Trigger.caseReporter: line 7, column 1: []
"

```
trigger caseReporter on Case (after insert) {

List<Case> cs = new List<Case>{};
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    Case dummy = new Case(createdById = record.createdById);
    list<User> users = new List<User> {};
    users = [Select Name,Email from USER where user.id= :dummy.createdById limit 1] ;
    record.Report__c = users[0].email;
    System.debug(record.Reporter__c);
    cs.add(record);
  }
   insert cs;
}
```

Comment: Is your code bulkfied ?..putting a SOQL inside a loop may cause gov limit exceptions

Answer (score 3):

1) I don't think this code compiles.

```
record. = users[0].email;
```

2) If it did somehow work past this, you would run into an error by trying to insert a record that you already inserted.

```
trigger caseReporter on Case (after insert) {
  List<Case> cs = new List<Case>{};
  for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    cs.add(record);
  }
  insert cs;
}
```

3) You cannot make changes the records causing the trigger to fire in an **after** trigger.  You would need that in a **before** trigger.

```
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
  record. = users[0].email;
```

Also, please point out the line you get your error on because we have no way of knowing which line is 7.

Comment: Hey sorry for the typos, I shall correct it. Thanks for the help